# How to keep Action Bar on top

Tags: android, android-actionbar

My Action Bar shows up on the bottom, how can I control it to show up on the top? 
I am following [this tutorial](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/adding-action-items-and-overflow-menu-items-to-action-bar-in-android/).

A picture that explains what I want to do.

[image: picture]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Action Bar shows up on the bottom, how can I control it to show up on the top?

Remove `android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow"` from your manifest.

> A picture that explains what I want to do.

That is not possible with the action bar, sorry.

Comment: By removing that not everything shows up on the top. How do I get rid of the ActionBarMenu text that shows the name of the project.

Comment: Look at [ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(boolean))

Comment: @Ammar: "By removing that not everything shows up on the top" -- the items that do not fit are in your overflow area: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2012/01/say-goodbye-to-menu-button.html In your screenshot, that's the `...` thing.

Comment: It works when I add 'android:showAsAction="always" to all the items. Is this how to do it or do you recommend another way? If this the way to go, you answered my question.

Comment: @Ammar It's considered bad practice to abuse `showAsAction="always"` like that. Prioritize what really needs to be there; read the "Action Buttons" section of this article for more info: http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html#elements